# Need a view that acts like a log view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to implement a view that acts as a log view, so that when you push a message into it, the message would push other messages upwards.
Is there anything like that for iOS?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily implement that using standard UITableView:

- Each cell will be responsible for displaying 1 log message
- Add new cell to the end of the table when new message arrive
- Scroll table to the bottom after cell is added (using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method with `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom` position parameter)

That means you'll need to store your log messages in array, but if you're going to display them you need to store messages anyway

Comment: Some time ago I created storage for logs so basically you can use that proposed solution in viewController and use [this](http://iosmagic.com/iosmagic/node/4) as a model, it keeps logs in NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

@Vladimir's answer is probably the way to go, but just for the sake of seeing some additional options, here's an example using a UITextView:

```
- (IBAction)addNewLog:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *myInputText = @"some new text from string";
    NSString *temp = myTextView.text;
    [myTextView setText:[temp stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@: %@",[NSDate date],myInputText]]];
    [myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, myTextView.contentSize.height - myTextView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];

}
```

Then if you wanted to separate the text in the text view into objects in an array:

```
NSArray *myAwesomeArray = [myTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Mind you, the above would break if the "myInputText" string ever contained a line break.